# React-Native Authentication Login with Token AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native

I have 2 pages, a login, and a home. I use react-navigation to navigate between screens.
When I will log in I post my username and password and get the token from the response.
How to set the default screen in Home when in async storage there's a token. And when there's no token will automatically redirect to login, and also when logged in it'll no able to go back to the login screen.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, best way for us to help you is for you to post any relevant code and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const AppNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Lunario,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
            color={config.color.white}
            name="menu"
            style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
          />
        ),
      }),
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  }
);
```

that's my app navigation and before navigate to Home, will check if there's a token redirect to Home, pass the Login screen